# AngularJS http request is never executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a minimal plunk of this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVblhH?p=preview).

Here's what's happening:

1. initial `$http` request is made successfully
2. a click event is bound to a button in a directive
3. clicking the button fires the desired function
4. the `$http` request in that function (identical to the request in step 1) does not fire

Because the code is short, I'll post it here, too.

#### template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <!-- angular source -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Click this button and an http request should log to the console</p>
    <button make-request act='flip()'>Get Gaius</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

#### controller

```coffee-script
app = angular.module('plunker', [])

app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope, $http) ->
  # this function is just here to show that no errors are thrown
  err = (err) -> console.log 'err', err

  # this successfully gets
  $http.get('gaius.json')
    .then ((res) -> console.log 'init data', res.data), err


  $scope.flip = ->
    # although this function is called,
    console.log 'called to act'
    # http does not get. No request is made.
    $http.get('gaius.json')
      .then ((res) -> console.log 'flip data', res.data), err

app.directive 'makeRequest', ($compile) ->
  scope:
    act: '&'

  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    element.bind 'click', (e) -> scope.act()
```

#### data

```json
{
  "name": "gaius baltar"
}
```

Any idea why that request doesn't execute?

Comment: I was encountered this issue few weeks ago and the solution was to call $digest. Alas, this does not work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to propagate promise resolution, by calling $apply() on the scope.

```
app.directive 'makeRequest', ($compile) ->
  scope:
    act: '&'

  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    element.bind 'click', (e) -> scope.act(); scope.$apply();
```